# Set Entity Framework Connection String at Runtime in C#

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I need to set my Entity Framework connection string at runtime. Right now, I have the following:

```
string connectionString = "metadata=res://*/DataModels.CustomerDataModel.csdl|res://*/DataModels.CustomerDataModel.ssdl|res://*/DataModels.CustomerDataModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=tcp:{serverName},{portNumber};initial catalog={databaseName};user id={username};multipleactiveresultsets=True;application name=EntityFramework&quot;";
using (CustomerEntities entities = new CustomerEntities(connectionString))
{
  CustomerEntity entity = new CustomerEntity();
  // do more
  entities.CustomerEntities.Add(entity);
  entities.SaveChanges();
}
```

When I execute the code above (with the {parameter} values replaced), I get the following error:

> *Keyword not supported: 'data source'.*

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Change this.

```
string connectionString = "metadata=res://*/DataModels.CustomerDataModel.csdl|res://*/DataModels.CustomerDataModel.ssdl|res://*/DataModels.CustomerDataModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=tcp:{serverName},{portNumber};initial catalog={databaseName};user id={username};multipleactiveresultsets=True;application name=EntityFramework&quot;";
```

To this (note how i escaped the " character as "" )

```
string connectionString = @"metadata=res://*/DataModels.CustomerDataModel.csdl|res://*/DataModels.CustomerDataModel.ssdl|res://*/DataModels.CustomerDataModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string= ""data source=tcp:{serverName},{portNumber};initial catalog={databaseName};user id={username};multipleactiveresultsets=True;application name=EntityFramework""";
```

Answer (score 7):

I know this was asked 10 months ago, but I found an easier way to specify the connectionString:

If your config file has it as:

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="CustomerDataModel" connectionString="metadata=res://*/EntityFramework.CustomerDataModel.csdl|res://*/EntityFramework.CustomerDataModel.ssdl|res://*/EntityFramework.CustomerDataModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=.\CustomerDataModel;initial catalog=CustomerDB;integrated security=True;multipleactiveresultsets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

You can specify it as -

```
public const string ConnectionString = @"name=CustomerDataModel";
..
CustomerDBContext context = new CustomerDBContext(ConnectionString );
```

No need to worry about quotes. Lot cleaner.

Answer (score 6):

It is easier to use [EntityConnectionStringBuilder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entityclient.entityconnectionstringbuilder%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [SqlConnectionStringBuilder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnectionstringbuilder.aspx) to change parameters as you want.

Answer (score 3):

set multiple connection strings in your web.config, and follow below:

```
public partial class MyDatabaseEntities
{
    public MyDatabaseEntities(string connection)
        : base(connection)
    {
    }
}
```

and then wherever you want to create instance of entities, pass connection string name in parameter:

```
MyDatabaseEntities entities = new MyDatabaseEntities("CONNECTION_STRING_NAME");
```

I hope this will help.

Thanks