# Entity Framework database first and dynamic connection string for 100+ SQL Server databases

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am new to Entity Framework and want to know how to modify the connection string in code.

Here is my code

```
using (var context = new PushjobModel.PushjobEntities())
{
    var list = context.GetAllActivePushjobs();

    foreach (PushjobModel.Pushjob item in list)
    {
        item.IsActive = false;
        item.IsSent = true;
    }

    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

I have a configuration file in my ASP.NET webforms application which contains a list of connection strings for 100+ databases. Before I call `context.GetAllActivePushjobs();` I want to change the connection string.

With old **ADO.NET** I have been using following approach for long time and it works perfectly

```
spPremisesReadTableAdapter taPremises = new spPremisesReadTableAdapter();

taPremises.Connection.ConnectionString = GetConnectionString(CompanyName);

taPremises.GetData();
...

public static void GetConnectionString(string CompanyName)
{
    string connectionstring = System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[CompanyName].ConnectionString;
}
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Set Entity Framework Connection String at Runtime in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14673559/set-entity-framework-connection-string-at-runtime-in-c-sharp)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20064284/1730559

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to provide the name of the connection string entry to your constructor of your `DbContext`:

```
using (var context = new PushjobModel.PushjobEntities(name-of-connection-string-here))
{
   .....
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I created another connection string on the pattern of entity framework and it worked

Comment: existing connection strings in config file in the format  <add name="test100" connectionString="data source=(local);initial catalog=TestXYZ100;Integrated Security=True""></add> is there any way so that I can pass this connection string and its converted into entity framework style connection string because I have to create duplicate connection string now one for old ado.net connectivity and otherone for entity framework connectivity

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are looking for is the class `EntityFrameworkConnectionStringBuilder`

Take a look at [MSDN page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entityclient.entityconnectionstringbuilder(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

May be you could try this:

```
using (var context = new PushjobModel.PushjobEntities(GetConnectionString(CompanyName)))
{
    var list = context.GetAllActivePushjobs();

    foreach (PushjobModel.Pushjob item in list)
    {
        item.IsActive = false;
        item.IsSent = true;
    }

    context.SaveChanges();
}

public static void GetConnectionString(string CompanyName)
{
    string connectionstring = System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[CompanyName].ConnectionString;
}
```